# Changing part of the screen in when button clicks in Blackberry

Tags: blackberry

I have  three buttons in on screen,when i click each button it navigate to corresponding button contends.i need to change part of the screen without changing whole screen.Can anyone give an idea about this.

Thank You

Comment: Without knowing the specifics of what you want to change it's difficult to know where you are stuck. That could be updating the text inside a LabelField, or adding/removing an item from a VerticalFieldManager. So my answer assumes that you have some manager you can already make a change to but you are not seeing the change.

Comment: i need to change vertical field manager fields

Comment: I've added that to my answer.

Comment: Hi,can u give example  code for multiline text box with rounded rect

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Generally speaking if you modify a manager you should invalidate that manager which is the way to tell the device a repaint is required.

http://www.blackberry.com/developers/docs/4.0.2api/net/rim/device/api/ui/Manager.html#invalidate()

**Edit:** information about adding to/deleting from VerticalFieldManager
The documentation specific to a VerticalFieldManager is here:
http://www.blackberry.com/developers/docs/3.7api/net/rim/device/api/ui/container/VerticalFieldManager.html

The methods you should use to update its child fields are all inherited from the Manager class. You can also see a list of other subclasses here:
http://www.blackberry.com/developers/docs/3.7api/net/rim/device/api/ui/Manager.html

E.g. Check the methods for delete, deleteAll, deleteRange, insert, add.

Answer (score 1):

Besides Ray's answer I think you should look to replace method:

```
 vfm.replace(oldField, newField);
```

On a thread:

```
public void run() { //this is your Runnable for your Thread
//do stuff
UiApplication.getUiApplication().invokeLater(new Runnable() {
    public void run() {
        vfm.replace(oldField, newField);
    }
});}
```