# How to change button on button click in blackberry

Tags: user-interface, blackberry

I want to change button on same button click how i can do that in blackberry. i used frame layout in android for overlay two field one after above so how i can change field on same click in blackberry?

like e.g i want to kept two buttons on same position when i click btn1 btn2 should display and when i click btn2 btn1 should display

Comment: use custom image button. Refer http://rincethomas.blogspot.in/2012/04/custom-image-button-in-bb.html

Comment: i want to kept two buttons on same position when i click btn1 btn2 should display and when i click btn2 btn1 should display

Comment: do you want **one** button that switches between two **images**, or two different buttons (and if so, why)?

Comment: no i want two buttons

Comment: Is this BB Java or BB10 C/C++/Cascades?  If BB Java, have you looked at the Manager replace() method, to swap one button with another.

Comment: ya it is about BB java can please give me any sample code or something i am newbie in blackberry i searched not getting anything about Manager replace() method

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hay i done with replace method thanks for all of u for reply

i used 
vfm.replace(oldField, newField);
to swap

[Changing part of the screen in when button clicks in Blackberry](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7061870/changing-part-of-the-screen-in-when-button-clicks-in-blackberry)  //here is the link